# jquery function inside function loop

Tags: jquery, sqlite, loops

hi i am in mobile app and i have the following problem.

i want to select data from table bill for each barcode from table billpayments.

here is me code

```
        t.executeSql('SELECT barcode, amount, receiptno FROM billpayments WHERE receiptno > 0', 
            [], function(t, resultcollect) {
                len = resultcollect.rows.length;

                    for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
                        row = resultcollect.rows.item(i);
                        t.executeSql('SELECT barcode, buildingcode, flatdescription FROM bill WHERE barcode = ?', 
                            [row.barcode], function(t, collectaddress) {
                                mybill = collectaddress.rows.item(0);
                                list.append('' + mybill.buildingcode + ',' + mybill.flatdescription + ',' + row.receiptno + ',' + row.amount + '</br>');
                        });


                    }
                    tameio = tameio.toFixed(2);
                    list.append('<table border="1">' + items.join('\n') + itemspay.join('\n') + '</table><p>' + tameio + '');
            });
```

but in html append i receive for row.receiptno and row.amount for all barcodes the last value...

Please help i am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the iteration, `row` is overwritten over and over again. To solve the issue, create a new scope, in which `row` is a local variable, using a helper function:

```
function dummy(i) {
    var row = resultcollect.rows.item(i);             // <-- Local variable
    t.executeSql('SELECT barcode, buildingcode, flatdescription FROM bill WHERE barcode = ?', 
        [row.barcode], function(t, collectaddress) {
            var mybill = collectaddress.rows.item(0); // <-- LOCAL variable!
            list.append(mybill.buildingcode + ',' + mybill.flatdescription
                         + ',' + row.receiptno + ',' + row.amount + '</br>');
    });
}
for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
    dummy(i);
}
```

Comment: @user1081978 This is a common mistake. I hope that you've learned to never do this again ;)